# Getting full path URLs in views/templates

Tags: playframework

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/main.css'}">
```

`@{'/public/stylesheets/main.css'}` returns the relative path: `/public/stylesheets/main.css`

How do I get the full path?
i.e. `http://www.something.com/public/stylesheets/main.css` inside the view/template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use

```
@@{'/public/stylesheets/mains.CSS}
```

instead of using single @. See [this PlayFramework Template Cheatsheet](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/cheatsheet/templates) for example.

---

From [PlayFramework Templates Documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1/templates#Actionsor) explains it as:

> The @@{…} syntax does the same but generates an absolute URL (notably
>   useful for e-mail).